# android read the text from NFC tag

Tags: android

I managed to write this code to read the NFC UID, I need to read also if there is a text in the NFC tag, how can I add it? The app should read the nfc UID & TAG and needs to save is as a static variables

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    TextView uidView;
    static String strNFCUID;

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uidView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_uid);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                uidView.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        if(nfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Nothing in NFC" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            byte[] id = tag.getId();
            // Change the binary value to hex string..
            strNFCUID = bin2hex(id);
            uidView.setText(strNFCUID);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Discovered something in NFC!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }       
    }

    static String bin2hex(byte[] data) {
        return String.format("%0" + (data.length * 2) + "X", new BigInteger(1, data));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Enable device to get signal..
        enableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Disable device to get signal..
        disableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }
    private void enableForegroundDispatchSystem() {
        if(nfcAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        IntentFilter[] intentFilters = new IntentFilter[] {};
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilters, null);
    }
    private void disableForegroundDispatchSystem() {
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(MainActivity.this);
    }  
   }
}
```